# How to use same form in laravel for upload file?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

How to use  same form in laravel for upload file?

I use same form for uploading images in laravel.

```
{!! Form::file('featured_img', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

When i submitted the form, it worked like a charm. but it didn't work when i submitted at edit mode. i try to var_dump the request and got this.

add mode :

```
[featured_img] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object ( 
...
)
```

edit mode :

```
[featured_img] => maintenance.jpg
```

What should i do?

Comment: why not using different layout for edit and create? so you will have 2 form? and have different url for post...

Comment: if we can use same form... why not?

Comment: so you can use the same form? but the form is not working haha...

Answer (score 0):

sorry it's my mistake I forgot to add :

```
   'files' => true, "id"=>"registrasi"
```

so, my code change like this.

```
    @if( isset($posts) )
        {!! Form::model($posts, [
        'action' => ['Admin\PagesController@postEdit', $posts->idpages],
        'files' => true, "id"=>"registrasi"]) !!}
    @else
        {!! Form::open(['files' => true, "id"=>"registrasi"]) !!}
    @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(isset($data->featured_img))
    {!! Form::file('', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
@else
    {!! Form::file('featured_img', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is not change anythings. i think you didn't get my problem